# How to create functions using for loops?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting, function

I'm trying to use a for loop to create functions for choosing passwords in my Arch install script (based on [easy-arch](https://github.com/classy-giraffe/easy-arch/blob/main/easy-arch.sh)) using the following code (which uses [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268764/how-to-repeat-prompt-to-user-in-a-shell-script/268769#268769) se answer for repeating prompts and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command/15696250#15696250) one for adding newlines to read):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
errEcho() { echo -e "${BOLD}${BRED}[ ${BBLUE}•${BRED} ] $1${RESET}"; }
for type in encrypt user root; do
    pick_${type}pass() {
            read -rsp "Enter $type password: " ${type}pass
            read -rsp $'\nVerify password: ' ${type}pass2
            echo
            if [ "$typepass" != "$typepass2" ]; then
                errEcho "Passwords don't match."
                return 1
            fi
            return 0
    }
done
until pick_userpass; do : ; done
```

When this is run I get the following errors (last line is spammed until script gets terminated):

```
./looptest.sh: line 3: `pick_${type}pass': not a valid identifier
./looptest.sh: line 3: `pick_${type}pass': not a valid identifier
./looptest.sh: line 3: `pick_${type}pass': not a valid identifier
./looptest.sh: line 15: pick_userpass: command not found
```

Does anyone know how a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: don't. Use one function and pass parameters to it.
Using an associative array:

```bash
pick_pass() {
    local type=$1
    local pass pass2
    while true; do
        read -rsp "Enter $type password: " pass
        read -rsp $'\nVerify password: ' pass2
        echo
        [[ "$pass" == "$pass2" ]] && break
        errEcho "Passwords don't match."
    done
    password[$type]=$pass
}

declare -A password

for type in encrypt user root; do
    pick_pass $type
done

declare -p password
```

Not particularly illustrative, but running it:

```
declare -p password
Enter encrypt password:
Verify password:
Enter user password:
Verify password:
Enter root password:
Verify password:
bash: errEcho: command not found
Enter root password:
Verify password:
declare -A password=([encrypt]="foo" [root]="asdf" [user]="bar" )
```